# Upload Configurable product from FTP

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have Magento 1.9 integration with ERP for Product, inventory, order. My ERP does not include the Configurable Product feature like multiple inventory for same product with different size, but our ERP team advice that they can provide the config. product in the CSV format of Magento config. product.

Can you please provide any way to handle this situation?